# Momentjs returning different results on firefox compared to chrome

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Just by typing out this line on firefox and chrome

```
moment("September 2015") < moment("September 2015").endOf('month')
```

I get true on chrome and false on firefox, how can i make the result be more consistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the momentjs docs http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/

> Browser support for parsing strings is inconsistent. Because there is
>   no specification on which formats should be supported, what works in
>   some browsers will not work in other browsers. For consistent results
>   parsing anything other than ISO 8601 strings, you should use String +
>   Format.

So you could specify the format like

```
moment("September 2015", "MMMM YYYY") < moment("September 2015", "MMMM YYYY").endOf('month')
```

and it should work the same.